# Cancel notification when the process is destroyed

Tags: java, android, push-notification, media-player

I have a media player app which has a notification for the playback controls.
The problem is when the process is killed the notification still stays and I want it to disappear. any recommendations?

Comment: firstly, when `process is killed`, there is no way to execute any code because the process is killed. Maybe you mean something different under `process is killed`?

Comment: I mean right before it killed.

Comment: nothing will be called `right before it killed`. If the process is killed, it is killed instantly without any lifecycle methods. There is no way to know when the process is going to be killed.